# Creative Ziio and android development, adb

Tags: android, windows, driver, adb, tablet

Soo, I think this might be early, but I have a need for usb debugging drivers for this Creative Ziio 7" tablet I have in front of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had need for the same thing.

I found this forum thread that specifies how to use the Google driver in order to access the device (instructions for both Linux and Windows).  At the very least it was able to recognize my Ziio, however it was unable to access the screen.  (I don't know if it is suitable for debugging though.)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=882105

Comment: I dont have the tablet any more :(, but this looks good so Ill accept.